# How to pass object in Thymeleaf + Spring flow without values

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

From Search page, User can click Create New button. If user enter p_no in Search page, and then user click Create New, this number is being carried out to Create New page. But actually it should not pass the value. What is wrong with the code below.

PersonEntry.HTML(Create page) :

```
<form id="entry" action="#" th:object="${person}" method="post">
    <div id="boxes">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pno" th:value="${person.p_no}" disabled="disabled" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller.java:

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/searchPersons")
public class SearchPersonController {           
@RequestMapping(value = "/createNewbtn", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView creatNewPerson(Person person) { 

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(); 
    modelAndView.setViewName("PersonEntry");
    return modelAndView;

}
}
```

Search.HTML:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready( function() { 
         createActionURL = function(obj) {
             $("#seach").attr("action", obj);
         }
         createActionURL(); 
        }); 
</script>
<form id="search" action="#" th:object="${person}" method="post">
<div class="col-md-1">
    <input type="text" size="2" class="form-control" id="p_no" th:field="*{p_no}"></input>
</div>
<div class="row" align="right" style="width: 100%">
    <input type="submit" value="Create New" class="btn btn-primary" id="createNewbtn" th:onclick="'javascript:createActionURL(\'' + @{/searchPersons/createNewbtn} + '\')'" 
/>  
</div>  
</form>
```

Can anyone help on this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me

```
<script>
     $(document).ready( function() { 
         $('#createNewbtn').click(function{
               $("#seach").clearForm(); // clearForm function will be called to clear necessary input values.
         })
         createActionURL = function(obj) {
             $("#seach").attr("action", obj);
         }
         createActionURL(); 
        }); 
</script>
```